# How to set minimum and maximum length of a string argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this so far:

```py
@app_commands.Argument(
  username={
    "min_length": 3,
    "max_length": 22
  }
)
async def inv(interaction:discord.Interaction, username:str):
  # code
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 69, in <module>
    @app_commands.Argument(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

How do I make it so that the min and max length of the `username` argument is `3` and `22`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using [app_commands.Range](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#range).

```py
async def inv(interaction:discord.Interaction, username:app_commands.Range[str, 3, 22]):
  # code
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the documentation of Discord.py.

These lines of code are incorrect.

In fact the error that is reported: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'`
does not means that you set in the wrong way the Arguments, but only that the constructor of `Argument` does not take this kind of data, the only parameter that want the `@app_commands.Argument` is `Parent` and `Data`.

Then you have to take into consideration the fact that the `@app_commands.Argument`is not a callable object so also the lines below are wrong.

The correct way  to initialize an object of type `Argument` as you wish is the following:

```
a = discord.app_commands.Argument(parent="", data = {'type' : 3,'name': 'username','required' : True,'description':'', 'max_length': 22, 'min_length': 3  })
```

then if you print `a` you will see:

```
<Argument name='username' type=<AppCommandOptionType.string: 3> required=True>
```

but if you print `a.to_dict()` you will see this:

```
{'name': 'username', 'type': 3, 'description': '', 'required': True, 'choices': [], 'channel_types': [], 'min_value': None, 'max_value': None, 'min_length': 3, 'max_length': 22, 'autocomplete': False, 'options': [], 'name_localizations': {}, 'description_localizations': {}}
```

so the `Argument` class is correctly initialized.

If we see in the `models.py` file the constructor of Arguments:

```py
    def __init__(
            self, *, parent: ApplicationCommandParent, data: ApplicationCommandOption, state: Optional[ConnectionState] = None
        ) -> None:
            self._state: Optional[ConnectionState] = state
            self.parent: ApplicationCommandParent = parent
            self._from_data(data)
```

we can see that it take 2 arguments.
Than we can analyze the function `_from_data` :

```
def _from_data(self, data: ApplicationCommandOption) -> None:
        self.type: AppCommandOptionType = try_enum(AppCommandOptionType, data['type'])
        self.name: str = data['name']
        self.description: str = data['description']
        self.required: bool = data.get('required', False)
        self.min_value: Optional[Union[int, float]] = data.get('min_value')
        self.max_value: Optional[Union[int, float]] = data.get('max_value')
        self.min_length: Optional[int] = data.get('min_length')
        self.max_length: Optional[int] = data.get('max_length')
        self.autocomplete: bool = data.get('autocomplete', False)
        self.channel_types: List[ChannelType] = [try_enum(ChannelType, d) for d in data.get('channel_types', [])]
        self.choices: List[Choice[Union[int, float, str]]] = [Choice.from_dict(d) for d in data.get('choices', [])]
        self.name_localizations: Dict[Locale, str] = _to_locale_dict(data.get('name_localizations') or {})
        self.description_localizations: Dict[Locale, str] = _to_locale_dict(data.get('description_localizations') or {})
```

and we can see that the only arguments that are mandatory are:

- `type`
- `name`
- `description`

the other one are optional and you can set or not set it

Comment: Yes. I have read [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=modal#argument) and two of the parameters are `min_length` and `max_length`.

Comment: you can see updated answer for more detailed information